# multiple sets of complex roots of a number?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, roots-of-unity

I am not sure if this question was asked before but I couldn't find the right keywords to choose for searching.

So today I discovered a weird problem:
If we take this equation: $$x^2=1=e^{(0i)}$$
this equation has 2 solutions : $\{1, -1\}$
Until now everything is normal.
but if we wroted like this: $$x^2=x^{\frac{4}{2}}=\sqrt{x^4}=1$$
what happens is that this becomes: $x^4=1^2=1$
and now it has another set of roots: $\{1,-1,i,-i\}$
And we can continue as much as we want getting an infinite number of sets of roots

My question is how is this happening?
Did I make an illegal operation?
Did I miss something?

P.S.: I am not a mathematician, so I could have missed something here (that I probably didn't learn)

*UPDATE*
My most important reason for asking is how to deal with equations like this: $$x^{\frac{a}{b}}=c$$ where a and b are 2 integers and you can simplify $\frac{a}{b}$

*UPDATE*
Obviously i and -i are not solution for $x^2=1$
But if we had from the beginning this equation: $x^\frac{4}{2}=1$ (which is exactly the problem I am waiting for its solution as I mentioned in my previous update above)
we have 2 options simplify to $x^2=1$=>we have only two roots
or do not simplify=>we have four roots and they are all valid: $i^\frac{4}{2}=\sqrt{1^4}=1$ (valid)

so 2 sets of roots
**tl;dr: to simplify or not to simplify?**

Comment: You have discovered that $(\pm i)^2=-1$.

Comment: @Dr.MV no you misunderstood my question. I have clarified it more (probably) x^2=x^{\frac{4}{2}}=\sqrt{x^4}=1

Comment: There is more than one extended discussion on the site about fractional exponents.  One thing that needs to be kept in mind is that the interpretation $ \ x^{m/n} \ = \ \sqrt[n]{x^m} \ = \ ( \ \sqrt[n]{x} \ )^m \ $ is only simple for $ \ x \ > \ 0 \ $ .  [Otherwise, we need to use the more complete definition of complex roots.]  The other thing is that the rational number in the exponent carries a _specific_ meaning and that the meaning is altered if that rational number is "simplified".  So $ \ x^{2/6} \ $ is _not_ the same function as $ \ x^{1/3} \ $ , since they have different domains.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, applying $()^2$ to both sides of an equation can alter the set of solutions. It's not necessarily an equivalent transformation:

$$-1=1$$
$$(-1)^2=(1)^2$$
$$1=1$$

In math it's mostly true that $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1$ but if you ever cut yourself accidentally you know that two halves of a finger ain't equivalent to a whole one. The used equality is not strict in this regard.

I think removable singularities are another example. Is the function $f(x)$ defined at $x=5$?

$$f(x) = \frac{3x^2-11x +20}{x-5}$$

No. Dividing by 0 is not defined. Wait! What's this?

$$f(x) = \frac{3x^2-11x +20}{x-5}=\frac{(3x+4)(x-5)}{x-5}=3x+4$$

Now it looks like 5 is a very valid value.

You should always be careful when simplifying something. Always check your solutions with the original form to see if they apply for it as well.

Comment: isn't applying $()^2$ the thing we CAN do and applying $\sqrt{()}$ the thing we CAN'T do directly? (if x=y then $x^2=y^2$)

Comment: @PhpLou you _can_ certainly do it. You can do all kinds of things. You can also multiply everything by 0. The question is if the resulting statement is equivalent to the one you started with. As I've shown in my answer, this is not necessarily the case.

Comment: I am not proving that $x^{\frac{4}{2}}=1$, I am trying to solve it. That is different

Comment: @PhpLou no it's not: whatever transformation you apply, you have to make sure that the result is equivalent to what you started with. Please read the last two sentences of my answer again.

Comment: Ok you are right with this. I asked my question in a wrong way. Can you confirm or refute my last update?

Comment: @PhpLou this looks very similar to the removable singularity problem. I'd say do not simplify and/or point out that the simplification yields a different result. Is $x$ even a complex number?

Answer (score 0):

Certain exponent laws and properties go out the door when you start dealing with complex numbers. That's why you're getting to different solutions when going about this in two different way.

In general, if $n$ is an integer, then the solution set to the problem $z^n = 1$ is the set of roots
$\{1=e^{2\pi i * (0/n)},e^{2\pi i * (1/n)},e^{2\pi i * (2/n)},\ldots,e^{2\pi i * ((n-1)/n)}\}$

Comment: can you answer my question (I posted it after your response)

Comment: In general $a^b$ is defined to be $e^{b\log a}$ whenever it's not super obvious (super obvious makes sense when $a$ is non-negative and $b$ is real. The main issue is specifying the right branch of $\log z$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm is not a bad source. The parts you won't understand are irrelevant for this question. The stuff you can understand are things that are pertinent.